# Compare List Similarity Python

Tags: python, approximate

```
S = ['hom']
L = ['home','honda','Hammer','Elephant']
```

I want to get output to show similarity

```
hom = home
```

and

```
print home
```

How I can do this? I want to use approximate matching to change "hom" to "home".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For something built-in, you have [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html).

It can (as said in the docs): Return a list of the best “good enough” matches. word is a sequence for which close matches are desired (typically a string), and possibilities is a list of sequences against which to match word (typically a list of strings).

The example in the docs is:

```
>>> from difflib import get_close_matches
>>> get_close_matches('appel', ['ape', 'apple', 'peach', 'puppy'])
['apple', 'ape']
```

Comment: If you can't figure out what to do given this example then you don't know enough programming to be able to use a fully coded example. Work through an introduction book on Python then come back to this problem.